# LayoutInflater and setText doesn't work together

Tags: android

I'm using my Android project activity ( Navigation Activity Drawer ) . When I want to change the title at the top in the side menu , it is not working . I used a LayoutInflater to read the ID from the XML right , but nothing . this is my code :

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String EXTRAS_NOME = "nome";
private static final String EXTRAS_COGNOME = "cognome";
private static final String EXTRAS_CODICE = "codice";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_dashboard, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome);
    textView.setText("hi"); //The text does not change. Why?


}
```

**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />
```

**nav_header_dashboard.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNomeCognome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/omega"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**@tiny sunlight return this error with your code**

```
01-23 14:26:33.640 3272-3272/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.application.andreamarconicola.progettoandroidam, PID: 3272
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.andreamarconicola.progettoandroidam/com.application.andreamarconicola.progettoandroidam.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.application.andreamarconicola.progettoandroidam.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:53)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**the solution is this . Thank you @tiny sunlight**

```
//Thanks @tiny sunlight ... now work
    TextView textView = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome);
    textView.setText("ciao");
```

Comment: Where u are using `nav_header_dashboard ` layout?

Comment: You are inflating a **new** view from `nav_header_dashboard` where you actually should update the already existing view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_dashboard, null);
```

will create a new View.You should use the view in NavigationView.

```
TextView textView =(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome);
```

I don't really know why I should getHeaderView(0).I guess the headerLayout hasn't been added to activity before the NavigationView shows.

Comment: You use inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_dashboard, null) to get a new View .It's not the view in NavigationView.

Comment: don't work. return this error: 

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Try navigationView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome);Can you show me your R.layout.nav_header_dashboard?

Comment: @Marco I think TextView textView =(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome); is right.

Comment: give me a minute , now I try .

Comment: I don't really know.I think it has not been added to the activity.It will be added to activity when you open the drawer.You can try to findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome)  in NavigationItemSelectedListener.I think you can get it.

Comment: anyway thanks for the help . now it works perfectly . how do I say that this answer is the solution ? so I close the question asked.

Comment: You needn't to close it.It will help others have same quesition.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating a layout while there is another one displayed inflated via `setContentView()`.

your code does change the title for an object in memory that's not displayed.

Assuming `R.id.txtNomeCognome` is a text view in layout `R.layout.activity_dashboard`  you can use `findViewById()` to get your view object and set the text on it

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNomeCognome);
```

Comment: I simply created a new Navigation Drawer Activity
and added a LayoutInflater . xml files and java are created automatically by Android.

Comment: the setContentView method already inflates your layout, binds it to the activity and  displays it. 
Also activity has findViewById method that you can use directly to get an already inflated view.
So why do add Layout inflater ?

Comment: if I do not use LayoutInflater returns an error ( Object null )

error message:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference